# The "for" loop suddenly be infinite after changing the order of variables

Tags: loops, for-loop, lua, conditional-statements

I just recognized that the order of the returned variables does affect how the "for" loop work, which is a pretty interesting thing

```
local function FakeIpairs(t) --The factory
  local i = i or 0 --The control variable
  
  local function Iterator() --The iterator function
    i = i + 1 --Increment the control variable 
    v = t[i]
      return v, i
  end 
  
  return Iterator
end 
arr = {1, 9, 8, [5] = 10} 
for v, i in FakeIpairs(arr) do 
  print(v)
end 
--[[ 1
     9
     8 --]]
```

I changed the order of the variable and this happens

```
local function FakeIpairs(t) --The factory
  local i = i or 0 --The control variable
  
  local function Iterator() --The iterator function
    i = i + 1 --Increment the control variable 
    v = t[i]
      return i, v --[[CHANGED HERE]]
  end 
  
  return Iterator
end 
arr = {1, 9, 8, [5] = 10} 
for i, v --[[AND HERE]] in FakeIpairs(arr) do 
  print(i)
end 
--[[ 1
     9
     8
     nil
     10
     nil
     nil
     nil...--]]
```

It became an infinite loop immediately without any conditional statement (I put a conditional statement into the function and it worked fine).

What is the relationship between the `for` loop and the order of returned variables? Why the code would keep `return v, i` and incrementing `i` forever if I changed `v, i` into `i, v`?

Comment: You should only return `i,v` when `v` is not `nil`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is explained in the reference manual [The generic for loop](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.3.5)

> The first of these variables is the control variable.

and later on

> If the control variable becomes nil, the loop terminates. Otherwise, the body is executed and the loop goes to the next iteration.

In the second example, the first variable is the index (the control variable). The index is incremented at each iteration and never becomes nil. And when the control variable never becomes nil, the loop never stops.

Comment: Oh the first variable returned by the iterator function is called *the control variable*. I  thought the control variable is `i` .

Comment: In the first example `v` is the control variable of the for loop, in the second example the control variable is `i`.